# How can I get notified when a UIView becomes visible?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

Is there a way to get a notification, a callback or some other means to call a method whenever a UIView becomes visible for the user, i.e. when a UIScrollview is the superview of some UIViews, and the ViewController of such a UIView shall get notified when its view is now visible to the user?

I am aware of the possible, but not so elegant solution of checking to which position the ScrollView scrolled (via UIScrollViewDelegate-methods) and compute if either one of the subviews is visible...
But I'm looking for a more universal way of doing this.

Comment: The navigation of my app is based on scrolling a UIScrollView horizontally. I am also intercepting touches via a subclassed UIWindow. The ViewController of the currently visible view therefore needs to register itself as delegate to the subclassed UIWindow. And this is the reason I want to get notified if a view becomes visible.

Answer (score 9):

I've managed to solve the problem this way:

First, add a category for UIView with the following method:

```
// retrieve an array containing all super views

-(NSArray *)getAllSuperviews
{
    NSMutableArray *superviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(self.superview == nil) return nil;

    [superviews addObject:self.superview];
    [superviews addObjectsFromArray:[self.superview getAllSuperviews]];

    return superviews;
}
```

Then, in your View, check if the window-property is set:

```
-(void)didMoveToWindow
{
    if(self.window != nil)
        [self observeSuperviewsOnOffsetChange];
    else
        [self removeAsSuperviewObserver];
}
```

If it is set, we'll observe the "contentOffset" of each superview on any change. If the window is nil, we'll stop observing. You can change the keyPath to any other property, maybe "frame" if there is no UIScrollView in your superviews:

```
-(void)observeSuperviewsOnOffsetChange
{
    NSArray *superviews = [self getAllSuperviews];
    for (UIView *superview in superviews)
    {
        if([superview respondsToSelector:@selector(contentOffset)])
            [superview addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
}

-(void)removeAsSuperviewObserver
{
    NSArray *superviews = [self getAllSuperviews];
    for (UIView *superview in superviews)
    {
        @try
        {
            [superview removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"];
        }
        @catch(id exception) { }
    }
}
```

Now implement the "observeValueForKeyPath"-method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"])
    {
        [self checkIfFrameIsVisible];
    }
}
```

Finally, check if the view's frame is visible inside the window's frame:

```
-(void)checkIfFrameIsVisible
{
    CGRect myFrameToWindow = [self.window convertRect:self.frame fromView:self];
    if(myFrameToWindow.size.width == 0 || myFrameToWindow.size.height == 0) return;
    if(CGRectContainsRect(self.window.frame, myFrameToWindow))
    {
        // We are visible, do stuff now
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. I an trying it out, but the problem is that superviews are being deallocated before I have a chance to remove their observer. I am even observing changes to their "superview" key path but it does not help. This is definitely the worst part of KVO.

Comment: This should be no problem, I guess. If a superview gets deallocated, the observing view (the view of which we want to know if it is visible), should be deallocated, too, since it is a subview.

Comment: You are right. My issue was that I was failing to call `removeObserver` on all the key paths. That said, KVO best practice is to retain ownership of all observed objects. In this case, this means placing the list of superviews created by `observeSuperviewsOnOffsetChange` in a member variable, and using this retained superviews list in  `removeAsSuperviewObserver`. This also has a slight performance benefit.

Answer (score 7):

If your view is exhibiting behavior, it should be within a view controller. On a view controller, the viewDidAppear method will be called each time the view appears.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: The problem with viewDidAppear is, that it only get's called when using a Navigation-Controller. In my case, the views get *scrolled* off the screen, then get scrolled back. Scrolling seems not to trigger viewDidAppear....

Comment: So what can indicate if the view is appeared on screen with scroller?

Comment: " it should be within a view controller." - and view controllers only work with full screen views. Sometimes we have views that cover only a part of screen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a universal way to do this for views. Sounds like you're stuck with scrollViewDidEndScrolling and other ScrollViewDelegate methods. But I'm not sure why you say it's elegant, they're quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

view's layer property should tell us if that view is visible or not

```
[view.layer visibleRect];
```

but this isnt working for me.

So work around could be to use UiScrollView contentOffset property to calculate if particular view is visible or not.

Comment: So how do you add a trigger that's fired when that value changes?

Comment: I answered this question long ago, even i forgot the context. 

Subclass UIView and use following methods. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW139

Comment: that's what I'm doing now. I want to listen from an outside class.

Comment: Then you prolly need to implement delegates. Define your own custom delegate.