# Determining a visible part (frame) of UIView subclass, that is added as a subview to cell in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

Let's call this UIView subclass - SomeClass. This SomeClass is a part of a static library. Some customer will use this library and will add instances of this SomeClass to the cells of his (customer's) table view.

I (SomeClass) need to determine when the SomeClass "enters" screen (will become visible), and when will  "exit" screen (will become non-visible).

I can use `didMoveToWindow:` method and then check `self.window` for nil. BUT, there is a problem, SomeClass gets this event, before it is actually visible, because of cells "preparation" by table view concept. And I need to know for sure, it is 100% visible by some user.

1. One way to determine is by using `scrollViewDidScroll:`. Suppose SomeClass will get scroll view by using iteration on super views and will subscribe as a delegate to found scroll view. But he will be removed by some cell that will subscribe itself as a delegate to scroll view. So I need to invent here some solution for this. For example, in Android, there is possibility to add observer, in that case SomeClass is always a listener and is not overriding any other listener. There is many to one relation in Android, not like in iOS, one to one.
2. The other way, I can enable some timer in `didMoveToWindow:` when SomeClass becomes visible, that will check each X time, its frame. The timer will be disabled, when SomeClass will go from screen.
3. Probably there is a way to check at low level, without using scroll view and timer on some low-level redraw method. Is it possible?

So what is the best (will use less resources / good design) method?

Comment: have you read this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453457/iphone-howto-get-notified-when-an-uiview-becomes-visible

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CGRectIntersectsRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect) to check if the cell's frame intersects with the frame of your custom view. Aside from that, [didMoveToWindow](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/didMoveToWindow) is the method you are looking for.

If as you say the table view cell will always have SomeClass as a subview, then it would make more sense to use UITableViewDelegate [tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitableviewdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:).

Comment: SomeClass's frame always intersects cell's frame, he is added as a subview.

Comment: Have you read my question? I have described something about didMoveToWindow

Comment: In that case, abstract the logic out of your view and check it the view will be shown when the cell is displayed -- see my edit.

Comment: And in this solution, If SomeClass subscribes as a delegate to table view, it overrides customers table view delegate and vice versa, customers table view delegate always can override SomeClass.

Comment: tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: is where your logic should go if you need to do something as the cell will be shown. Have you thought that perhaps you are putting too much responsibility onto SomeClass? SomeClass is a view, it shouldn't have any logic in it.